# Could extended use of a cooler pad which places my laptop at a 20 degree angle hurt it?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

Specifically i'm worried about the hdd

I'm using it for gaming and i'm wondering if i can just leave it on the cooler pad at all times or if i should get a flat pad instead

Thank you in advance

Comment: the angle of the machine really doesn't matter for laptops - they're designed to be used at odd angles. I sometimes watch movies in bed laying on my side with my laptop on its side. Don't worry about anything...

Comment: Thank you, i guess i'm mostly concerned about leaving it at an angle permanently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but keeping your machine at an angle does not affect the mechanism of the laptop. It is  jerks and knocks to the machine  that might cause the moving parts of the hdd to bang against each other and damage it. You should be fine keeping your laptop at an angle for extended periods of time, in fact that should keep it cooler than when using a flat pad, so effectively less damage to machine from heating issues.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend taking it off the pad at night or should it be ok simply leaving it on the pad at all times?

Comment: just leave it, and don't worry!

Comment: If the fan noise doesn't bother you leave it on

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the noise it makes, leaving it on will be like leaving a 60watt bulb on all the time.  Will cost you about 1p a day on top of the other £1 or £2 of other stuff left on all the time...  In my opinion unless you lead a very active online life there is no need to leave the machine on all the time.  It will last longer that way too.
Like the previous answers, the angle of the machine will not affect it at all.  Moving it quickly in any direction while it is on does affect the HDD but nothing else.  If you are at all worried about the angle affecting it even after our advice and want a speed boost too for gaming then replace the HDD with an SSD.